How do you order C# methods by their access modifiers using editorconfig or SonarQube?
We agreed that we should implement a rule to enforce that private methods are below public methods, as this is explained in Clean Code page 84/85: "Vertical Ordering". I don't see any option in the editorconfig or in SonarQube to report a violation of access modifier ordering.
How can we change the configuration in either the editorconfig or SonarQube to report a violation in the vertical ordering of access modifiers?

Sounds like you need to create custom rule yourself.

Sounds like StyleCop rule SA1202

editconfig rule Order modifiers  applies to single statement.
You need to use Roslyn extension.
Check the  Order of items in classes: Fields, Properties, Constructors, Methods
